# Anybody know what happened to gmplayer in Maverick?

Tags: 10.10, mplayer, gmplayer

My long-term media player (for various reasons) has been gmplayer. A simple floating UI that remembered its fullscreen layout and just worked for me. I'm not trying to convert anybody but please respect that I'm not looking for alternatives.

It used to live in a package called `mplayer-gui`. Since upgrading to Maverick, I can't find it anywhere.

Apparently an Ubuntu-sent changelog says I should use SMplayer instead but as anybody who has used both will tell you immediately, they're completely different styles of media player.

I'm not against progress but I can't see anything but regression here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copied from [Bug 649240](https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mplayer/+bug/649240):

> mplayer-gui has been removed in
>   maverick because it is broken
>   upstream. It doesn't even build with a
>   shared avcodec ATM.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, but it appears to be resolved upstream: it builds fine since yesterday. :)

Comment: Wonder if it'll make it back in.